# Elixir convert string to map code not working

Tags: elixir

Good day developers, i'm having issues figuring out how to make a function work.

**Test case**

```
  test "count one of each" do
    expected = %{"one" => 1, "of" => 1, "each" => 1}
    assert Words.count("one of each") == expected
  end
```

And this is what i came up with so far.

```
@spec count(String.t()) :: map
  def count(sentence) do
    sentence
    |> String.split
    |> Enum.map([sentence], &(%{sentence => 1 , value =>&1}))
  end
end
```

The code itself doesn't work, can some one explain how can i achieve the following functionality based on the test i provided?

**Big thanks.**

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 4):

From your code it looks like you haven't understood how [pipes `|>`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.html#%7C%3E/2) or the [`Enum`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html) functions work. It would probably benefit you to read the documentation in more detail.

This should do what you want:

```elixir
"one of each"
|> String.split()
|> Enum.group_by(fn x -> x end)
|> Enum.map(fn {k, v} -> {k, length(v)} end) 
|> Enum.into(%{})
```

Explanation:

1. Split the string into a list.
2. Group the list into a map. The keys are the words, the value is a list containing each occurrence.
3. Convert each list into a count of its length
4. Return the result as a map

Answer (score 2):

Use `Enum.reduce`

```
  def count(sentence) do
    sentence
    |> String.split() 
    |> Enum.reduce(%{}, fn word, sentence_map -> 
        Map.update(sentence_map, word, 1, fn existing_count -> existing_count+1
        end) 
     end)
   end
```